# How to make a garden plan which pleases me?

Tags: identification

How to make a garden plan?

I red Piet Oudolf's Book called Planting the Natural Garden.

I would mimic his garden in Hummelo, see below. I could identify, basically his book says 4 plants about the attached photo.

But his garden is more varied. I even started to make my own garden plan, look below, but it is far from a professional garden plan I have seen.

What do you think?

1. Shall I be brave choose some perennials and grasses from his book beside these:

- Rhus typhina - ecetfa - 3
- Calamagrostis acutiflora ‘Karl Foerster’ - nádtippan - sok
- Achillea filipendulina ‘Parker’s Variety’ - Páfránylevelű cickafark
- Aster ‘Little Carlow - őszirózsa

I like those too:

- Sporobolus heterolepis - préricseppmag
- Darmera peltata
- Agastache nepetoides
- Monarda bradburiana
- Amsonia ‘Blue Ice’
- Allium atropurpureum
- Salvia nemorosa
- Agastache nepetoides
- Peucedanum verticillare
- Echinacea purpureax

2. How important do you think to have a 'precise' plan?
3. If I search a more experienced person, a gardener, landscape designer, I guess one will identify and choose with more expertese. How much value an expert can bring? Do you think I can be satisfied with my own work if I go after my own head?
4. Is it any online portal, service, where they would make a professional plan, based on my existing ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to check aggressiveness of the plants. For example, Rhus typhina spreads A LOT - up to 15m if it's happy.  Darmera peltata likes a moist site, and if given one takes off on a journey of exploration, out-competing much of your garden (it is better behaved if planted in dry shade). Other plants on your list will spread by seed.

Comment: This seems to be likely off topic as opinion-based. You make a garden plan to please you by making a plan, as detailed or vague as you like, and deciding that it pleases or does not please you, and then you implement one that pleases you (as a plan) and discover the truth of "no plan survives contact with the enemy" and revise or manage or hire an army of landscapers or...